# Что такое "Node.js command prompt" и где он расположен?

Tags: node.js, cmd

После установки Node.js у меня появились 2 ярлыка:
- **Node.js**
- **Node.js command prompt**

Оба - консоли. Внешне немного различаются. Работаю через вторую консоль с Gulp и npm.

1) В чём их разница и почему их две (консоли)?
2) Второй важный вопрос, где находится этот *"Node.js command prompt"* ? Путь указывает в папку cmd от винды - C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe. Но открыв эту cmd и *"Node.js command prompt"* я вижу различия в названии консоли, в надписях приветственных, короче это что то разное. А мне нужен точный путь именно к *"Node.js command prompt"*, что бы указать его в редакторе, что бы тот разрешил мне открывать из себя именно эту консоль и работать с командами gulp, npm без лишних действий и команд.

Comment: во втором случае сначала запускается `cmd.exe`, а затем `node.exe` (через `.bat`), это аналогично тому, если бы вы сами запустили `[win+r] > cmd.exe > [enter]` и там запустили `node.exe` (через `.bat`), посмотреть расположение программ можно в свойствах ярлыка

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, да, это оказался обычный cmd.exe, но запуская его после _"Node.js command prompt"_ пришлось заново устанавливать глобальные пакеты для работы, видимо cmd.exe и _"Node.js command prompt"_ имеют разные пути или хранилища, нет опыта, не знаю. Вот это и хочется именно понять.